# Rails 4 - if boolean is true then move object to true (without refreshing page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been googling around, but maybe my terminology is not allowing me to find answers I am looking for as I'm quite new to programming.

Basically, if an object is true (my checkbox has been checked and the object is completed) how can I then move that object off of the main page, and sort of 'archive' it I guess, with the completed objects only. All whilst staying on the same page.

E.g. user clicks checkbox, marks completed > object moves to completed > user stays in same page and can rinse and repeat cycle.

I'm not asking anyone to create this for me, far from it -- my question is, can anyone point me in the right direction on maybe rails doc or something to what I want to do so I can read about it and figure out how to do it?

Thanks & Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You would use Ajax (Jquery library) and potentially `.delegate()`.

Here's an example of Ajax:

Make a new JavaScript file in your javascript pipeline `/app/assets/javascripts/my_new_ajax_file.js`

In said file, you need to make the ajax call which has the capability of making an asynchronous call to a url which in your case I beleive you're looking for.

Let's say you have a route called `/api/v1/checkbox` which points to `Api#check`

(Assuming you have jquery included BEFORE this js file)
In your Javascripts file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.the_class_on_your_checkbox').click(function() {
       myAjaxCall();
    });
});

function myAjaxCall() {
$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',

    url: '/api/v1/checkbox/',

    data: {
        // Any data you need to send through
    },

    success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
    },

    error: function() {
        console.log("Something went wrong");
    }


});
}
```

Now, when you click on your checkbox, it will make a call to your route which I'm assuming you have defined in your controller.

You can now manipulate backend data in that action (Inside of your controller) and send and receive data from your database.

The way you send info back, it in the response (In the success function in the ajax call) you receive JSON from your controller like so...

```
def check
    render json: "OK"
end
```

Now in the Ajax call you can manipulate the JSON you receive back (Put whatever you need to from the database instead of OK)

If you need clarification of anything let me know, I don't know how much you do or don't know so I just tried to cover a bunch.

EDIT: Function typo

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that this is what I have already but in ajax? What I have is `<%= check_box_tag 'todo[completed]', todo.id, todo.completed, data: { remote: true, url: url_for(controller: :todos, action: :completed, id: todo), method: "POST" }, id: todo.id, :onclick => "Materialize.toast('Todo Completed, Grats!', 4000)" %>` in conjunction with my controller this marks as completed and updated the database, but doesn't move it to a todos/completed route. Sorry because I am quite new, I don't know too much right now, beginner level :(

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want to update object without refreshing page.
so you have to use ajax request

Comment: Sorry, to clarify - my object updates without refreshing the page, but once it's updated I want that object to go somewhere else, e.g. from the todos#index to todos#completed

Comment: so add new column to your table and make query on it.

for example add new column: `is_completed` set it `boolean` value. and than search `MyTable.where(is_completed:true)` in your  `todos#completed`

Comment: This is what I did originally - but it only updated the page upon refreshing, any ideas on how to update without the need of refresh? For example; It updated the checkbox without refreshing and saves to the DB however, it only goes to todos#completed view once the page is refreshed. I want it to automatically update to completed view.

Comment: so you should render js template inside your todos#completed
`respond_to do |format|
 
end`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the documentation a read now and give it a try!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735866/rails-rendering-the-js-erb-template-using-the-controller?answertab=active#tab-top good answer

Comment: What I'm not too sure of is what do I put here `$("#new_grouping").html("<%= escape_javascript(...) %>">` I'm looking around and one said my link so for example '/dashboard/home' but this didn't seem to do anything. Could you give me a brief example if possible? It would really help me.

Comment: your should put it inside your action template.
create completed.js.erb and put it there. its like view template but for js